# Android app gift code implementation

Tags: android, google-play

i've got a paid app at the android market and i would like to share some gift codes, so someone can get it for free.

There is no support for gift codes at the android market.

My idea was to make a free version of my app and lock it. If someone gets a gift code, he can download the free app and unlock it with a gift code.

I would like to know if there could be any problems with the android market or google if i upload a "locked" free app?

Or maybe some has a better idea how to solve that problem...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple website to generate codes, then attach the website URL in your app description at the market So when the user opens the website link gift code will be shown :-D , That's more easier I think :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem was the part after redeeming a gift code. How should i implement the unlock of that paid app with the gift code? Because of that i wanted to make a free locked app, which one can unlock with a gift-code, but maybe there is a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

One way you *could* do what you need will be as follows:

- Your user gets a gift code from somewhere (preferably your website).
- The user goes into a section of your app where they can *redeem* the gift code (for example in the *unlock app* menu option).
- This gift code is then sent to your server for validation. How you validate this is a whole different topic, but I'm trying to keep this abstract.
- Your server then responds with the equivalent of *yes* or *no* depending on whether the user entered in a valid gift code.

If done right (on your server end), you can effectively guarantee that gift codes can't be used more than once, which also implies they can't be shared (if already used).

The main **downside** of this method is that if/when someone reverse-engineers your app, unlocking its full capabilities will be quite trivial. Granted the probability of this depends on how much these *gift codes* cost, if it's worth it, etc, but this is something you should be aware of.